# I'm curious about python list's initialization and reference

Tags: python, list, reference, copy

Let me make a list and change one element like this:

```
list = [float("inf")] * 3
list[2] = 0
```

then I print it, It prints

```
print(list)
> [inf, inf, 0]
```

I thought each element references the same one, but it's not.

However, when I make a second-dimension list and change one element like this:

```
list = [[float("inf")] * 3] * 3
list[2][2] = 0
```

then I print it, it prints

```
print(list)
> [[inf, inf, 0], [inf, inf, 0], [inf, inf, 0]]
```

then I am in chaos.
in the first dimension, changing one element reflects to one element.
but in second dimension, all rows reflect the change.
how can it be happen?

I thought the second result should be:

```
print(list)
> [[inf, inf, inf], [inf, inf, inf], [inf, inf, 0]]
```

and according to the second result, shouldn't the first result be like this?

```
print(list)
> [0, 0, 0]
```

please, help me. I can't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what happens in the first example:

```
nums = [float("inf")] * 3
nums[2] = 0
print(nums)
# [inf, inf, 0]
```

After the first line is executed, all of the list elements *do* reference the same object.  You can see this by printing all their `id`s and seeing that they're the same:

```
>>> nums = [float("inf")] * 3
>>> for n in nums:
...     print(id(n))
...
2996959434960
2996959434960
2996959434960
```

The part you misinterpreted is what happens when you do `nums[2] = 0`.  This does not mutate one of the `inf`s (because they are in fact all the same object, which is itself immutable).  Assigning something to an object's name never modifies the *object itself*, only the *name*.

So subscript assignment mutates the *list* so that it's 2-th index (i.e. one of the 3 "names" for that one `inf` object) now references a *different* object:

```
>>> nums[2] = 0
>>> for n in nums:
...     print(id(n))
...
2996959434960
2996959434960
2996958396624
```

When you have a list of references to the same list, and you mutate the inner list, the top-level list is unchanged, so it sees the inner list change across all three of its "names".

It may help to think of:

```
nums = [float("inf")] * 3
```

as being equivalent to:

```
n = float("inf")
num0, num1, num2 = n, n, n
```

All three `num` variables point to the same `n`.  When you reassign one of them:

```
num2 = 0
```

you reassign *that variable*, but you're not changing `n` or any of the other `num`s.

The same exact logic applies if you do:

```
nums = [float("inf")] * 3
arr0, arr1, arr2 = nums, nums, nums
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your comment is perfect. I understand it at once!

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication operator (*) repeats the sequence which is list in this case, making shallow copy of the elements. The references to the elements are copied, but not the objects they point to.
[Here is the image for the explanation!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKJMR.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, thanks for contributing. In future, it is best practice to avoid images of code and to instead copy and paste the code/results into your answer with the appropriate formatting. This makes the code searchable, easy to re-use and also reproduce results.